# Python Dictionary : Check if a list of nested keys exists in a dictionary and update value

Tags: python-3.8

I have a dictionary, something like as follows

```
{
  "level1": {
     "level2": {
       "level3": "some value"
     }
  }
}
```

The keys in the dictionary will be dynamic. however, there will be a list of keys that needs to be checked.

Eg: `['level1', 'level2', 'level3']`

I need to check if a path exists in a dictionary such as level1->level2->level3 and if exists update the level3's value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set value for existing key in nested dictionary without iterating through upper levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621832/set-value-for-existing-key-in-nested-dictionary-without-iterating-through-upper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```py
def check_or_update(dct: dict, key_list: list, value) -> bool:
    d = dct
    for key in key_list[:-1]:
        if key in d:
            d = d[key]
        else:
            return False

    if key_list[-1] not in d:
        return False
    d[key_list[-1]] = value
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get(d, keys):
    return reduce(lambda d1, key: d1.get(key, {}), keys, d)

# check if key exists
print(not bool(get(the_dict, ['level1', 'level2', 'level3'])))
```